# Detect OS from attached USB, copy folders/files accordingly

Tags: c++, bash, batch-file

**The problem:** I have a USB, that can be plugged into different machines *(Windows, Linux, MacOs and Android)*. Without installing any script to these machines; I need a script to copy all files and folders **from a given folder name** (sfolder) which is always the same and at a given location on these machines, **to this USB** and send some signal to the com port.

I can write a simple windows batch file to copy the files and send some text to a given com port. Or some mini c++ code using SHFileOperation and COM to do the same thing. *(works)*

I can also write a bash file for linux (and am guessing that the command cp will be more or less the same for MacOS / Android) to do the same thing.. *(works)*

Any idea on how to detect different Operating Systems? via C/C++ or Batch / Bash files through autorun.inf?

*p.s. this is some hardware that acts like a usb drive, which switches between connected and not connected at random intervals, acting like a one-way folder/file collector for an isolated non-network NAS.*

Comment: `autorun.inf` is a Windows specific construct.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: [WINE is able to emulate this functionality](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/autorun)  In which case the WINE layer should also make the Windows-targetted autorun script function.

Comment: It is not reasonable to expect that WINE or Windows are installed and functioning on anything that a USB is stuck into.

Comment: The short answer is no - you'll need to find some external means to convince your victim to run your code.

Comment: @TobySpeight no 'victim', just a isolated, non-network NAS device which works this way; randomly connecting to devices without using network protocols.

Comment: If all your target OSs have Python on them (a fair assumption): you could accomplish the OP objectives with only one Python script (utilizing `os.path` et al.)

Comment: Possible further route to think about: if Python is not available on all target OSs, you could still write the Python script, and then convert it to an executable C/C++ with a Python compiler (e.g., https://code.google.com/p/shedskin).